# how to fix this "Because my app depends on flutter from unknown source "camera", version solving failed."

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image: the error image]

I already have my camera versions in pubspec.yaml

I am expecting for it to run and have a camera access and if I dont have any cameras, I w have a code that says "No camera found"

I am trying to have camera access in my flutter code for my mobile app development.

I always use "flutter pub get", my identations are correct I dont know what to do

Comment: Can you please post an exact copy of the error message in the body of your question?

Comment: i inserted it @nvoigt

Comment: Can you post your pubspec? It looks like something is wrong there.